# needrestart behaves differently when run by ansible instead of a manual ssh connection

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run the [needrestart](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/needrestart) tool by ansible to check for processes with outdated libraries.
When I run needstart with the command or shell modules from ansible it says that I need to restart my ssh daemon. When I run needrestart manually it says that there are no processes with outdated libraries.

When I restart the ssh daemon it does not make a difference. But after rebooting the remote server the ssh daemon is not listed as a service I should restart anymore.

So I really do not understand the difference between the ssh connection from ansible and my manual ssh connection that causes the different behavior of needrestart.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance and best regards
Max

**My local machine**

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13

$ ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0.0

$ cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
ask_vault_pass = True
retry_files_enabled = False
```

I am using a ssh proxy to connect to the server:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@jumphost.example.com"'
```

**The remote server**

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.6

$ python -V
Python 2.7.9
```

**Using ansible**

```
$ ansible example.com -m command -a 'needrestart -b -l -r l'
Vault password: 
example.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
NEEDRESTART-VER: 1.2
NEEDRESTART-SVC: ssh.service

$ ansible example.com -m shell -a 'needrestart -b -l -r l'
Vault password: 
example.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
NEEDRESTART-VER: 1.2
NEEDRESTART-SVC: ssh.service
```

**Using SSH**

```
$ ssh example.com 'needrestart -b -l -r l'
NEEDRESTART-VER: 1.2
Killed by signal 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an active connection with older version of ssh process. When ssh restarts it does not terminate current copies which keeps active connections. If it would do this, than `ssh servers sudo service ssh restart` would kill active connection and you'll have a broken server.

So, when you do `systemctl restart sshd`, you restart only ssh-part, which accepts new connection. All existing connections are served by old ssh.

Why do ansible keep ssh old ssh connection between runs? Because of the ControlMaster feature. It keeps active ssh connection between runs to speed up new runs.

What to do? Close active ssh connections on your machine. Try `ps aux|grep ssh` and you'll see a process which serves as ControlMaster. Kill it, and outdated connection should be closed.